# Bash escape from script

Tags: bash, scripts

I have a simple app launcher script used to open a few apps in a ceratain folder on a certain workspace:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -n "$2" ]] 
    then
        wmctrl -s $2
fi

terminator --working-directory=$1 &
subl $1 &
smartgithg.sh $1 &
chromium-browser &
```

when I run it:

```
petr@sova:~$ open_project work/dyme/ 4
petr@sova:~$ #### some message or whatever
#### the console hangs here, and I need to <ctrl>+c in order to use it again
```

How do I "escape" from the command and maintain a regular console prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to for off subshells you can use the builtin

> ()

special characters to do so. To run them in the background use your

> &

You can read more about subshells here : [Subshells at TLDP Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html)

This would lead to

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -n "$2" ]] 
    then
         wmctrl -s $2
fi

(terminator --working-directory=$1) &
(subl $1 )&
(smartgithg.sh $1 )&
(chromium-browser )&
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help. The console still hangs. Any more ideas?

Comment: Yes. It'll help if you tell me if can you tell which command it hangs on ? For instance, does it show the chromium browser before hanging ? To be thorough with testing this. Append a final line to the script  

    _echo "Return to Shell"_

Comment: thanks for help, I'll give it a try once I get some time and will inform you